# Definition of simplified tags in NLP?

Tags: python, nlp, grammar, tagging, pos-tagger

I'm having trouble trying to find a good resource that would tell me what simplified tags in `NLP` mean. I understand that you can use:

```
nltk.help.upenn_tagset()
```

to help determine what the tags mean if we are using unsimplified version of tagging; however, I can't find a resource for the simplified version.

I really am only working with:

```
PRON
VERB
NOUN
DET
ADJ
ADV
PRT
ADP
CONJ
NUM
```

I can obviously get what some of these mean, but am having trouble with others (i.e. `PRT`...etc.)

Can anyone help point me to a resource in defining these tags?

Comment: See [A universal part-of-speech tagset](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/37072.pdf) by Petrov, Das & McDonald.

Comment: thanks, that was helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are now part of the [Universal Dependencies project](http://universaldependencies.org/) -- see this [page](http://universaldependencies.org/u/pos/index.html) for detailed information about the universal part-of-speech tags.